# Keep Tab visible in TabPane header

Tags: java, javafx, controller

Is it possible to always show the first tab in a the `TabPane` header, no matter how many tabs are in the `TabPane`?

I want a home tab for tiles and I have a `TabpaneController` for handling the tabs. I have the home tab always on the first position, but if I add more and more Tabs, it slides at the left side of the screen.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. What do you mean by "first position"? Tab order is left to right by default. Do you want this tab to be on the right side? or?

Comment: I want the "home tab" always on left side AND visible all the time. The tab slides away if I add more and more tabs on the right. Is it possible to set the home tab as always visible on screen, so it does not change its position (in the tab row). It is always on first Position, but not always visible on Screen.

Comment: @FranziskaGerlich can you add [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?